# Unity instantiated objects that do not affect each other

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, instantiation

I am instantiating objects every time a key is pressed and changing its size based on variables. Every time I press another key to instantiate a new object, it affects the size of the object that has already been instantiated.

The objects only stay on screen as long as same key is held down and destroyed when the same key is released. Each object is supposed to resize separately but they resize based on the latest morph that is cloned. They also all get destroyed after any key is released even if their original key is held down.

This is the function that instantiates the object.

```
public GameObject InstantiateMorph(Vector3 spawnPosition)
{
    // create a new object, set it to active (prefab is unactive)
    GameObject morphClone = Instantiate(morphObject, spawnPosition, Quaternion.identity);
    morphClone.SetActive(true);

    // add the morph clone to an array, get the latest morph clone in the array
    morphClones.Add(morphClone);
    latestMorphCloneIndex = morphClones.Count - 1;
    latestMorphClone = morphClones[latestMorphCloneIndex];

    Debug.Log("latest morphe index" + latestMorphCloneIndex);
    //latestMorphClone.transform.localScale = Vector3.one * 0;

    // get the scripts from the latest morph
    MorphSizeController morphSizeController = latestMorphClone.AddComponent<MorphSizeController>(); // Add MorphSizeController component
    SizeController2 sizeController = latestMorphClone.GetComponent<SizeController2>();

    // set the ID of the scripts to the _idCounter variable and increase the variable +1
    sizeController.targetID = _idCounter++;
    morphSizeController.ID = sizeController.targetID;
    sizeController.tag = sizeController.targetID.ToString(); 

    return morphClone;
}
```

These are the coroutines that Lerp the object size and destroy it once the lerps are complete

```
public IEnumerator PerformLerpChain(KeyCode keyPressed)
{
    MorphSizeController thisMorphSizeController = GetComponent<MorphSizeController>();
    if(thisMorphSizeController.ID == targetID)
    {
        GameObject latestGameObject;
        latestGameObject = this.gameObject;
        thisMorphClone = morphSpawnerScript.morphClones[this.targetID + 1];


        bool keyReleased = false;
        yield return StartCoroutine(LerpTransformWithKeyCheck(0, 1, attackTime, latestGameObject.transform, keyPressed, () => keyReleased = true));
        Debug.Log("Attack Lerp Finished " + keyPressed);

        keyReleased = false;
        yield return StartCoroutine(LerpTransformWithKeyCheck(1, sustainValue, decayTime, latestGameObject.transform, keyPressed, () => keyReleased = true));
        Debug.Log("Decay Lerp Finished " + keyPressed);

        if (!keyReleased)
        {
            // Wait for the same key to be released to continue from the second Lerp
            while (!Input.GetKeyUp(keyPressed))
            {
                yield return null;
            }
        }

        yield return StartCoroutine(LerpTransform(sustainValue, 0, durationRelease, latestGameObject.transform));
        Debug.Log("Release Lerp Finished " + keyPressed);

        //Destroy(thisMorphClone);
        latestGameObject.SetActive(false);
    }
}

private IEnumerator LerpTransform(float start, float end, float duration, Transform lerpingObject)
{
    //morphSpawnerFinder = GameObject.Find("MorphSpawner");
    //MorphSpawner morphSpawner = morphSpawnerFinder.GetComponent<MorphSpawner>();

    float startTime = Time.time;
    float elapsedTime = 0f;

    while (elapsedTime < duration)
    {
        elapsedTime = Time.time - startTime;
        float t = elapsedTime / duration;
        lerpingObject.transform.localScale = Vector3.Lerp(Vector3.one * start, Vector3.one * end, t);

        yield return null;
    }
}

private IEnumerator LerpTransformWithKeyCheck(float start, float end, float duration, Transform lerpingObject, KeyCode key, System.Action onKeyReleased)
{
    //morphSpawnerFinder = GameObject.Find("MorphSpawner");
    //MorphSpawner morphSpawner = morphSpawnerFinder.GetComponent<MorphSpawner>();

    float startTime = Time.time;
    float elapsedTime = 0f;

    bool sameKeyReleased = false;

    while (elapsedTime < duration)
    {
        elapsedTime = Time.time - startTime;
        float t = elapsedTime / duration;

        if(targetID == morphSizeController.ID)
            lerpingObject.transform.localScale = Vector3.Lerp(Vector3.one * start * 100, Vector3.one * end * 100, t);

        if (Input.GetKeyUp(key))
        {
            sameKeyReleased = true;
            break;
        }

        yield return null;
    }

    if (sameKeyReleased)
    {
        onKeyReleased?.Invoke();
    }
}
#endregion
```

I've tried everything from injecting a script when instantiating the object with values and adding ID's to the scripts to ensure only that object is being accessed.

I am using one script to instantiate the clones and place them inside an Array, then accessing them with the ID.

Comment: In `PerformLerpChain` where does `targetID` come from?  Because if it comes from SizeController2, then it will always be true for every instance.  You are allowing each instance to check against itself (since both SizeController2 and MorphSizeController are on the same object and have the same id) every time, so it will always be true for every object.